# Не открываются страницы в WebView Android

Tags: java, android, html, webview

У меня есть index.html, help.html, page_1.1.html, page_1.2.html. 
index.html - главная страница. 
На главной странице есть ссылка на сайт колледжа. Мне нужно было сделать так: при нажатии на ссылку открывается сайт колледжа отдельно в браузере, у меня получилось. А вот такие страницы, как help.html, page_1.1.html, page_1.2.html не открываются в приложении...

`public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    { if ("file:///android_asset/1c_workshop/index.html".equals(Uri.parse(url).getHost()))
    {
        return false;
    }
        Intent intenet = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intenet);
        return true;
    }
}`

Comment: Измените условие на подходящее - это всего-лишь сравнение строк. Вероятно подойдёт такое `url.startsWith("file:///android_asset/")`

Comment: @woesss у меня получилось, Вы правда очень меня спасли!